# Family sharing notifications

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, family-sharing

I am in a family with other people, but I am not the family organiser. I know that whenever I make a purchase from iTunes or the AppStore, the family organiser gets sent the invoice, but are they also notified about free downloads I make, such as apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only purchases that are not Tier 0 (Free) will cause an email to be sent.